# how to prevent build/index.html from being removed when building

Tags: reactjs, jenkins

We're using Jenkins and when our app is building, the service has stopped and said

> "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/spa/build/index.html' 500 "

And I found that when building, the `build/index.html` is removed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very unclear (to me). How is your build executed, i.e., what command and what configuration?

Comment: If you are talking in jenkins perspective then share the entire jenkins log.

Comment: @StephenKing not sure if I understand. we're using react app so  the command is "npm-run-all build-css build-js"

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does this command work locally? Maybe check the content of Jenkins' workspace by adding some `ls` output to your build...

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for the quick feedback. I've found that the code "fs.emptyDirSync(paths.appBuild);" in build.js script in react removed the ./bulid/index.html file. so I tested if the file is pasted or not. and it is pasted. As our service is running permanantly by pm2, feel like this would be solution. how do you think about it?

Comment: I have no clue about that